# When some one asks a question that is duplicate or has answer on another question, accept answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions, accepted-answer

When someone asks a question that is exactly duplicate or has answer to the question on some other question then rather than just upvote, shouldn't there be privilege to accept the answer as the solution to the new question too?

That will ensure credit is given to the answer as it solved another question too.

Comment: How is this different to closing the question as a duplicate?

Comment: then in that scenario there wont be any answer accepted right ??

Comment: Yes, that might be the case: [*per the usual SO definition of "answered", where the question must have an accepted or up-voted answer*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165933/changes-to-close-as-duplicate)

Comment: as there are moderators to monitor, if a question is marked as duplicate on some other question then atleast the accepted answer of duplicate question must automatically get an upvote as it answered another question on the site

Comment: If you want to involve moderators into this I would say no to that...

Comment: all those people who can mark a question as duplicate!